# Can't install sql server on amazon linux instance - Requires: systemd-units systemd and numactl-libs

Tags: sql-server, linux, amazon-ec2, installation, yum

I tried to install `sql-serven` on a `medium Ec2` with amazon linux and I get errors with a few packages.

I was using following command: `sudo yum install mssql-server`

And I get this error:

```
Error: Package: mssql-server-14.0.3076.1-2.x86_64 (packages-microsoft-com-mssql-server-2017)
           Requires: systemd-units
Error: Package: mssql-server-14.0.3076.1-2.x86_64 (packages-microsoft-com-mssql-server-2017)
           Requires: systemd
Error: Package: mssql-server-14.0.3076.1-2.x86_64 (packages-microsoft-com-mssql-server-2017)
           Requires: numactl-libs
```

When I tried to install the `systemd-units` package I got another error:

```
sudo yum install systemd-units
Loaded plugins: priorities, update-motd, upgrade-helper
amzn-main                                                                                                                                                                                                             | 2.1 kB  00:00:00
amzn-updates                                                                                                                                                                                                          | 2.5 kB  00:00:00
2 packages excluded due to repository priority protections
No package systemd-units available.
Error: Nothing to do
```

How can I solve this error?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sql-Server is not compatible with Amazon Linux 1, the only soltion for me was create an RDS.

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server does install successfully on Amazon Linux 2, so if you make sure you're using an Amazon Linux 2 AMI to launch your instance you won't get those errors.

For example, in US N. Virginia the current Amazon Linux AMI is ami-035b3c7efe6d061d5, that will not work, but the current Amazon Linux 2 AMI is ami-0cc96feef8c6bbff3 and it does work - I have used it myself.